# Make error library not found for -lstdc++fs

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

When compiling code examples from a textbook, I run into a compilation error: `ld: library not found for -lstdc++fs`. What does this error mean and how can I get around it?

```
% make filesystem           
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target filesystem
[100%] Linking CXX executable filesystem
ld: library not found for -lstdc++fs
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [chapter_17/filesystem] Error 1
make[2]: *** [chapter_17/CMakeFiles/filesystem.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [chapter_17/CMakeFiles/filesystem.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [filesystem] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**, linking `stdc++fs` is not longer necessary as it has been incorporated into the base library.

When the textbook was first written the C++ libraries didn't officially support filesystem yet, so they would require a secondary library called `stdc++fs`. This was a `libstdc++` specific library that imported the C++17 features that weren't in the official library yet.

Now, both GCC's `libstdc++` and Clang's `libc++` include it in their base library, and the `stdc++fs` library got dropped.

You can drop the linking to that library without any problems; it patched a problem in compiler support that's no longer relevant